# How do i view the command, with params, being executed by ExecuteReader in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am adding parameters to my SqlCommand. Here is a quick example (using only the properties concerning my question):

```
Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

cmd.CommandText = "af_get_data"
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", "param1")
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", "param2")
```

all i want to do is be able to see the command along with the parameters being sent to the DB while at a break point in debug mode. example:

```
exec af_get_data @p1='param1', @p2='param2'
```

i try to hover over **cmd** in debug mode, but the parameters property does not list the parameters, when i expand parameters and look for the items i see this:

"Item = In order to evaluate an indexed property, the property must be qualified and the arguments must be explicitly supplied by the user."

i do not want code to do this, i know there should be a way to view it in one of the debug windows somehow.

help is appreciated!

Comment: But you should at least be able to see the variable you assign to the parameter in the debug window. This should also work in the quick-watch window: `cmd.Parameters[0].Value`

Comment: some of my procedures have 20+ params. to sit there and copy and paste them one by one from the variables and construct the exec statement by hand is very tedious. this is why i am looking for a way to get the whole exec statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see exactly what is being sent to SQL Server, your best bet is to actually use [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx).

However, if you want to stay within Visual Studio, you can right-click on `cmd` and select `Quick Watch...` to dig into the details of the object. You may not find exactly what you are looking for however, which is why I suggest SQL Server Profiler.

Comment: though i would like to also find a way to see this in visual studio this was definitely the sort of solution i am looking for. on top of that, sql server profiler is something i need to gain more experience with in general, it looks like a powerful tool. thanks much, competent_tech!

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a seven year old question but maybe someone will find what I've been using valuable.

I have a generic query helper class I wrote which just centralizes a lot of crap. It looks like this. One if its functions looks like this:

```
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            AddParameters(command, parameters);
#if DEBUG
            string debug = CreateDebugSQL(sql, parameters);
#endif
            using (SqlDataReader results = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                return method(results);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since I don't want to open profiler just to get the string to check if everything is passing correctly to it, I put a function in which creates a debug string. It's a kludge, it's meant for debugging so it's not pretty and takes some trimming but:

```
static private string CreateDebugSQL(string sql, List<SqlParameter> parameters)
{
    string debugSQLString = sql.Substring(0, sql.IndexOf('@'));
    foreach (SqlParameter parameter in parameters)
    {
        string val = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parameter.Value.ToString()) ? "" : parameter.Value.ToString();
        debugSQLString = debugSQLString + parameter.ParameterName + " = '" + val + "', ";
    }
    return debugSQLString; //just so we can breakpoint here to read it
}
```

You'll surely want to adapt this to whatever you're doing but it's fairly reliable in reconstructing the SQL String.